# Meaning of 以 which is used inside 她16岁就开始以模特儿身份出道了。

Tags: grammar

> 她16岁就开始以模特儿身份出道了。
>
> She started her career as a model at the age of 16

I guess 就 here is used to emphasize the earliness of the start of the career.

I want to know the meaning and the role of 以 which is used inside the original sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer is, you can treat the 以 as "as" in you translation

Answer (score 0):

以 - with; to use; according to; so as to; in order to; by.

Note that, 以 can be replaced by 用, which means use, employ, apply, and operate.

- 她16岁就开始以模特儿身份出道了。= 她16岁就开始出道了 - 以模特儿身份。

My thinking is that "She already was a model when she entered her current line of work/career (acting/singing, say)".